# What are the freeware SPICE simulators available?

Tags: simulation, software, spice

Does anyone know of a freeware SPICE / circuit simulator?

> SPICE (Simulation Program with Integrated Circuit Emphasis) is a general-purpose, open source analog electronic circuit simulator. It is a powerful program that is used in integrated circuit and board-level design to check the integrity of circuit designs and to predict circuit behavior. [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SPICE)

Comment: Oh well, I confused circuit / board-level simulation with SPICE simulation.

Comment: Are you asking for freeware or open source?

Comment: I think the answer to the original question is "yes".

Comment: Will add now microcap v12 http://www.spectrum-soft.com/download/mc12cd.zip

Answer (score 52):

- ngSpice is available for gEDA.

  gnuCAP is also available for gEDA.

  LTSpice is free from Linear Technology.

I thought that one of the other analog chip makers had a spice too but I can't remember
who :(

I have been to a few talks on simulation given by physicists and EEs who have done
chip design. Each of the talks seems to end like this ---

- Except for simple circuits you will spend most of your time getting models
      and determining where the models need to be modified for your application.

  Unless you are doing work for an IC manufacturer the manufacturer will not
      give you detailed models.

  You will not be able to avoid a prototype.

  You should only simulate subsections of your design. Simulating the entire
      design is not usually practical.

Also most of the free simulators are not distributed with models. Re-distribution of
the models is usually a copyright violation. LTspice is distributed with models of
the Linear Tech parts. I am not sure the quality of the models. Most manufacturers 
do not want to reveal too many details about their process.

Comment: +1 for LTSpice. The most maintained one from my point of view

Comment: "Re-distribution of the models is usually a copyright violation"  [Tables of factual data are not copyrightable.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feist_Publications,_Inc.,_v._Rural_Telephone_Service_Co.)

Comment: Note that PSPICE has a model generator that you can feed with common values from datasheets for most of the discrete components. I don't know if LTSPICE or the others have it, they might.

Answer (score 18):

A free version of TINA, which includes Spice, is available from TI.

I use SIMetrix Spice, it is an option with the Pulsonix PCB software I use. It's a very good implementation, and a free demo version is available that is suitable for small circuits:

[SIMetrix](http://www.simetrix.co.uk/)

[This](http://www.spiceopus.si/) is a very nice SPICE that I investigated some years ago. It can be used with Eagle schematics.

Answer (score 15):

I found an excellent online [circuit simulator](http://www.falstad.com/circuit/) written in Java, and its free-and-open-source. You can play with the software by visiting the link, and wait for the applet to pop-up. (you need the [Java Player](http://www.java.com/getjava/))

Edit components and connections by right-clicking anywhere/on a component. You can build entire circuits using this and simulate it visually to understand how the circuit works. (voltage is shown in green/red, simply amazing) If you start with one of the gate [circuit examples](http://www.falstad.com/circuit/e-index.html), (choose it from the *Circuits* menu), then you can click on gates or digital signals to switch them on/off, and see your circuit react.

You can setup oscilloscope views on any connection too. *(see bottom of the pic)*

[image: Screenshot of circuit simulator - falstad.com]

Comment: This is a circuit simulator, but I don't think it has anything to do with SPICE.

Comment: @davr You are right. I took the liberty to edit the post and remove the SPICE mention so it will not confuse people.

Comment: It was definitely a good idea to remove the misleading reference from this answer, but the question is about SPICE - Why is an answer that doesn't even mention SPICE so highly voted?

Comment: Every Circuit is also an excellent circuit simulator not based on SPICE, for mobile devices (Android). I used to use it every time I wanted to have a feel about what a circuit did, it is very aesthetic and easy to use. (now I know PSPICE enough, why bother)

Answer (score 13):

my favorite spice engine is the one made by linear technology.  I saw ngSpice mentioned above but there is no good port to windows.  Its cool if you have the linux box.  But I find it has some compatibility issues and library import issues.

http://www.linear.com/designtools/
That is where LTspice is, they have filter design tools there too.

Comment: I have used LTspice for years and the Yahoo group is very active with help, support, demo files and expanding libary of models.

http://tech.groups.yahoo.com/group/LTspice/

Comment: LTspice is a windows app, but is designed to also run under WINE, so you can use it on Mac/Linux with an appropriate wine-based interface layer.

Comment: ngspice is based on Spice 3f5 while most commercial offerings used the Spice 2 code as a base. This does not mean they are worse since the Spice 3 rewrite is not all roses. Back to the point: the most important difference is the change in specification of nonlinear components (POLYNOMIAL vs. normal equation) which breaks many models and treating node names as strings (in the original Spice 2 they had to be numbers and were compared numerically `0 == 00`).

Comment: +1: LTspice is where it's at. Free, fast, large community, runs on Linux (with Wine).

Answer (score 12):

I use LTSpice

great info on how to use it:

http://www.element-14.com/community/thread/1811

In particular this tutorial:

http://highered.mcgraw-hill.com/sites/0073106941/student_view0/lt_spice_instructions_and_support_files.html

Answer (score 11):

There are a couple of heavy-duty packages and a lightweight program for Linux.

The serious packages are **[GEDA](http://geda-project.org/)** and **[KiCAD](https://www.kicad.org/)**. They are each a collection of programs that work well together (like Orcad); they include a schematic capture, a simulator, a waveform viewer, and a PCB layout tool. They are very sufficient except my professor requires the ".out" file generated by pspice, so I still have to use that.

The lightweight program is **[Oregano](https://github.com/drahnr/oregano)**. It's great for quick simulations. The libraries are quick and easy to use and find parts from. The schematic capture is much easier to use and prettier than the other programs. It uses either gnucap or ngspice for the simulations, so they're pretty good. One major drawback that I have found is that the waveform viewer does not provide a logarithmic view and there's no way to get data out of it.

Comment: Does KiCAD perform circuit simulation? I don't think so...

Comment: @GM Apparently it has some interaction with external SPICE simulators? http://mithatkonar.com/wiki/doku.php/kicad/kicad_spice_quick_guide

Comment: you can consider to use online editor with support to Ngspice package like EasyEAD. https://atadiat.com/en/articles/e-full-review-of-easyeda-circuit-eda-online-tool/

Answer (score 7):

You can use [Qucs](http://qucs.sourceforge.net/).

For logics circuits, you can use this great online simulator called [Logicly](http://joshblog.net/projects/logic-gate-simulator/Logicly.html).