# Software to design and simulate circuits?

Tags: design, software

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Circuit Simulation Software](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/7022/circuit-simulation-software)

My friend is starting to learn some basic electronics as a hobby, and i have some knowledge on the subject from school. So I am looking for a software that will allow me to design and visually simulate simple circuits, for example I want to make a couple of leds to blink using a few transistors, and I want the software to visually show me the leds blinking.

Is there any software that can do this?

Answer (score 2):

http://www.falstad.com/circuit/
I found the applet to be very helpful. It has many example circuits and you can create you own as well.

https://www.circuitlab.com/
Here is another one. It is a bit more polished. I haven't used it much though.

**EDIT:** [Falstad example transistor blinky LEDs](http://tinyurl.com/adbakq3)

Comment: The Falstad simulator has some nice features that so far as I can tell are unique.  Unfortunately, it also has some annyoing limitations and quirks.  The source code is available, but I've not read anything about what the procedure would be for tweaking it and putting it on a server so that schematics that make use of the tweaks could be used by anyone.