# Program for simulating circuits on linux

Tags: linux, simulation

Do you know any program that works on linux and can simulate complex circuits?

Comment: What do you mean for complex circuits?

Comment: I mean at least all analog elements (almost) and non-erroneous simulating big ones.

Comment: This is possibly duplicated with [What are the freeware SPICE simulators available?](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/1206/what-are-the-freeware-spice-simulators-available)

Comment: @oneat - Do you need complex digital simulation as well as analog (Through Verilog AMS or VHDL-AMS), or would you prefer a schematic based simulator?

Comment: @Daniel Grillo - Simulation $\neq$ SPICE!

Comment: @reemrevnivek, I can't understand. SPICE means Simulation Program with Integrated Circuit Emphasis. Why Simulation ≠ SPICE?

Comment: @Daniel - Mathematically, SPICE $\subset$ Simulation.  In prose, there are a wide variety of circuit simulators available, and SPICE is just one of the most popular simulator frameworks.

Comment: What kind of circuits are you making? Different SPICE engines are better at certain kinds of applications.

Comment: @whatsisname - ....And different simulators are better at an even broader variety of applications!

Comment: Survey questions are not a good fit for this site.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are the freeware SPICE simulators available?](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/1206/what-are-the-freeware-spice-simulators-available)

Answer (score 9):

The [gEDA project](http://www.gpleda.org/index.html) supports the [Icarus Verilog](http://www.icarus.com/eda/verilog/) (digital only, though [Verilog-AMS support is planned](http://iverilog.wikia.com/wiki/Development_Time_Line#Verilog_A.2FMS)), [GTK Wave](http://gtkwave.sourceforge.net/), [ngSpice](http://ngspice.sourceforge.net/index.html), and [Gnucap](http://www.gnu.org/software/gnucap/) simulators.  It has the advantage that you can compose your schematics, simulations, and PCBs in the same flow, instead of having to manually copy everything from your schematic editor into the simulator.

If you want to evaluate more options, the Wikipedia [comparison of EDA software](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_EDA_software), [Electronic circuit simulation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electronic_circuit_simulation), and [list of free (as in freedom) simulators](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_free_electronics_circuit_simulators) pages all contain useful links.

Answer (score 3):

There are several SPICE implementations for Linux, such as [SPICE OPUS](http://www.spiceopus.si/) (it's free). I used the Windows version some years ago, and found it quite good. It can use Eagle schematics, which is a plus.

Answer (score 1):

Try this [DC/AC Virtual Lab](http://www.dcaclab.com/en/lab), it works in browser, you will need Flash Player though ..

Answer (score 1):

Real-time java-script browser application:

[Circuit Simulator Applet](http://falstad.com/circuit/)

Answer (score 0):

This is not an electronics oriented software, but it does work: try Xcos from Scilab.

Scilab is included in most distributions.
Xcos comes preinstalled.

Xcos is to Scilab what Simulink is to Matlab.

It has a GUI interface with components you can connect.

Answer (score 0):

[LTSpice](http://www.linear.com/designtools/software/) is actually Windows software but runs well under Wine.  I use it on Ubuntu.

Answer (score -1):

it is easy. Virtualize a copy of Windows within Linux and run your favorite windowed simulator in the windows box .